# How to create json array containing array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, arrays

how to create this type of array in javascript??
my array structure as below

```
{
   "Name":"Mr.X",
   "Name":"Main Outlet",
   "data":{
      "company":{
         "company_id":"5",
         "company name":"texas LTD.",
         "owner_name":"MR jack",
         "owner_email":"ss@dd.com",
         "owner_mobile":"999999",
         "comp_product":[
            {
                "Productid" : "1",
                "Productname" : "samsung"
            },
            {

               "Productid" : "2",
               "Productname" : "nokia"

           }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: The content of the json array is string or from some response?.  Please explain more

Comment: And do you mean to access that content in JavaScript? Just parse it and you can access `object.Name` or `object.data[0].company[0].company_id` etc...

Comment: You cant use the property `Name` twice, you have to use unique property names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you cant keep sample key name in object like "Name"

```
var details = {};
details["Name"] = "Mr. X";
var company = {};
company["company_id"] = "5";
company["owner_name"] = "MR jack";
//company[...] = ...;
var company_product = [];
{
    var comp_product = {}; 
        comp_product["productid"] = 1;
        comp_product["productname"] = "samsung";
    company_product.push(comp_product);
}
{
    var comp_product = {}; 
        comp_product["productid"] = 2;
        comp_product["productname"] = "nokia";
    company_product.push(comp_product);
}

company["comp_product"] = comp_product;

details["data"] = company;

alert(JSON.stringify(details));
```

Answer (score 1):

use this site to check the validity of your json http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ and then you can use

`JSON.parse('{"Name":"MrX"}')` to give you a json object array

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what are you trying to do there (you have only 1 array), but this might be a great help:
http://www.jsonschema.net/